# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
import math
import os


class collection:
    col = [[0 for col in range(5)] for row in range(6)]
    dist = [[0 for col in range(6)] for row in range(6)]
    filename = ""
    result = ""

    def __init__(self,arg1):
        self.filename = arg1

    def coll(self):

        for i in range(6):
            try:
                if(i==0):
                    f = open(self.filename,'r')
                elif(i==1):
                    f = open("chap1.txt",'r')
                elif(i==2):
                    f = open("chap2.txt",'r')
                elif(i==3):
                    f = open("chap3.txt",'r')
                elif(i==4):
                    f = open("chap4.txt",'r')
                elif(i==5):
                    f = open("chap5.txt",'r')

                for j in range(5):
                    self.result = f.readline()
                    self.col[i][j] = self.result
            finally:
                print "file handling error"

    def distance(self):
        for i in range[6]:
            for j in range[6]:
                dis = 0
                for k in range[5]:
                    dis += math.fabs((self.col[i][k]-self.col[j][k])*(j-i))
                self.dist[i][j] = dis
                self.dist[i][i] = sys.maxdouble
        return self.dist

class profile:
    dist = [[0 for col in range(6)]for row in range(6)]
    filename = ""
    pque = [[0 for col in range(6)]for row in range(6)]
    d = [[0 for col in range(6)]for row in range(6)]
    par = [[0 for col in range(6)]for row in range(6)]
    st = 0

    def __init__(self,arg1):
        self.filename = arg1

    def begin(self):
        ob = collection(self.filename)
        ob.coll()
        dist = ob.distance()

    def sssp(self):
        for i in range(6):
            pque[i] = sys.maxdouble
            d[i] = sys.maxdouble
        d[0] = 0
        pque[0] = 0

        while isempty()==0:
            u = extract_min()
            for i in range(6):
                if d[i]>d[u]+dist[u][i]:
                   d[i] = d[u]+dist[u][i]
                   pque_deckey(i,d[i])
                   par[i]=u
                if u!=0:
                    print u
            print "\n"
            for i in range(6):
                print par[i]

    def extract_min():
        ret = 0
        shift = 0
        minimum = pque[0]

        for i in range(6):
            if pque[i]<minimum:
                minimum = pque[i]
                ret = i
        pque[ret] = sys.maxdouble
        return ret

    def isempty(self):
        count = 0
        for i in range(6):
            if pque[i] == sys.maxdouble:
                count=count+1
        if count==6:
            return 1
        else :
            return 0

    def pque_deckey(self,im,di):
        pque[im]=di

class main:
    filename = raw_input("enter name of student:\n")
    filename = filename + ".txt"
    if(os.path.exists(filename)==1):
        f = file(filename,"r")
    else:
        f = file(filename,"w+")
        att1 = raw_input("att1 score:\n")
        att2 = raw_input("att2 score:\n")
        att3 = raw_input("att3 score:\n")
        att4 = raw_input("att4 score:\n")
        att5 = raw_input("att5 score:\n")
        f.write(att1)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(att2)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(att3)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(att4)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(att5)
        f.write("\n")
    stud = profile(filename)
    stud.begin()
    stud.sssp()
```

it shows a runtime error :

```
File "C:\Python27\winculum.py", line 33, in coll
    self.col[i][j] = self.result
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am just a beginner at python, and I am unable to rectify this even after searching on the net.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Anyway, your problem here is that you're using `col` as the iterator in your list comprehensions, and it's in the same scope as the external `col`, so it's overriding it. Just change `col` inside the comprehensions to something else.

Comment: hi !!
thanks for the valuable advice .. it worked

C

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The error:

```
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

means that you're attempting to apply the index operator `[]` on an int, not a list. So is `col` not a list, even when it should be? Let's start from that.

Look here:

```
col = [[0 for col in range(5)] for row in range(6)]
```

Use a different variable name inside, looks like the list comprehension overwrites the `col` variable during iteration. (Not during *the* iteration when you set `col`, but during the following ones.)

Comment: thanks for the advice ... can you please tell me how to assign maximum value of double to a variable ?

Comment: Use http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.float_info (I've just googled it up quite easily)

Answer (score 5):

This error could be an indication that variable with the same name has been used in your code earlier, but for other purposes. Possibly, a variable has been given a name that coincides with the existing function used later in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the problems:

```
for i in range[6]:
            for j in range[6]:
```

should be:

```
range(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also covert **int** to **str** first and assign index to it then again convert it to int
like this:

```
int(str(x)[n]) //where x is an integer value
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently while working on recursion and nested lists.
I declared:

```
print(r_sum([1,2,3[1,2,3],]))
```

instead of

```
print(r_sum([1,2,3,[1,2,3],]))
```

Note the comma after the number 3