# What does this specific error message mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner python user, and I am currently writing a program where if you input a number, it will tell you if the number is prime or not, but I am getting this error message, what does it mean?

```
"TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
```

If you need to see my code, please tell me, I am a beginner so I don't know much about these types of things. Sorry :(

Comment: We need to see your code.  That being said, somewhere you have an integer you're trying to call `getitem` on

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ for some steps to follow to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you try to apply the index operator [] on an int, not a list, like here:

```
>>> x=10
>>> x[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194110/int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an call for an index on something that isn't indexed (an example of an indexed item would be a List, while an example of one that isn't would be an int), you're going to get that error.

Produces error:

```
>>> my_item = 10
>>> my_item[0]
```

Does not produce error:

```
>>> my_list = [ 10, 11, 12 ]
>>> my_list[0]
```

---

While we're at it, here are some tips for posting to SO for the first time, for you and future viewers:

1. Just assume we need to see the problematic area of your code from the get-go.  No need to post the whole program, but summarize your problem as best as possible in the least amount of code required to recreate the problem.
2. Use formatting when posting a question.  When you originally posted, you wrote "**getitem**", when you should have written `__getitem__`.  A word or section of text surrounded by double underscores is interpreted as bold on SO.  Using the code sample formatting, you can have your text be interpreted as-is without transformation.