# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Python

Tags: python

My code is method of Euller for second ODE. I already try to do a function to define f this way 
{def inicial():
global f
f=matrix(M,N)}
But I had problem in the same line. I don't know how to recognize my function in that line.

```
N=101
x_min = -10.0
x_max = 10.0;
dx = (x_max - x_min)/(N-1)
dt = 0.25*dx*dx
t=0
t_max = 1000
Q=1
j=0
M=2
f = [N , M]



def f_xx(i,t):
  return ((f[i+1][t]-2*f[i][t]+f[i-1][t])/(dx*dx))


def guess(x):
  return ((pi*Q/x_max)*x +(pi*Q))


for i in range (N):
  for j in range(j):
    x = x_min + i*dx
    f[i][j] = guess(x)


  for j in range(t_max+1):
    for i in range(N-1):
      x = x_min + i*dx
      f[i][j+1] = f[i][j]+(f_xx(i,j)-sin(f[i][j]))*dt <<<error

   for i in range (N-1):
     f[i][j] = f[i][j+1]
```

What does mean 'int' object has no attribute getitem? Could anyone help fix it?

Comment: `for j in range(j)` is inappropriate because at the beginning  of your code you put `j=0` hence your 2D array `f` is not  initialized properly

Comment: I know, but was the only way that I found to fixed the column and increase the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['int' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194110/int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Answer (score 1):

`f` is a list containing two ints. `f[i]` refers to the the i'th int; so `f[i][j]`, will try and get the j'th value of an int, which cannot possibly work, whatever the value of `j`.

It's not clear what you are trying to do with this call, though.

Comment: I saw, but I can't define the function f to receive the value. Sometimes the column of the matrix is fixed and others is the line.

Comment: But you don't have a matrix. You defined f as aa simple one dimensional list.

Comment: How I do to define as a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use f as a list of lists (i.e. like a 2-dimensional array), but it's really just one list: [101, 2].

I'm rusty on ODEs but I think you were trying to create a 101x2 grid of 0s.  If so try f = [[0.0]*M for x in range(N)].

Comment: is a 2 dimensional array, but one time i fixed the column and other time i fixed the line. I already did on C++ but i can't do in python.