# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to create LCS problem and while compiling i am getting a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lcs.py", line 30, in <module>
    if x[int(i)] == y[int(j)]:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is my code as following:

```
from array import array
from pprint import pprint

def maxi(p, q):
 if (p > q):
      return p
 else: 
      return q

x="cgataattgaga"
y="lohttat"
n=len(x)
m=len(y)
l=[[0 for x in range(m+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
#Initializing the first row to be zero
for i in range(0,n+1):
    l[i][0]=0
#Initializing the first column to be zero
for i in range(0,m+1):
    l[0][i]=0
pprint(l)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):

        if x[int(i)] == y[int(j)]:
            l[i+1][j+1]=l[i][j]+1
        else:
            l[i+1][j+1]=maxi(l[i][j+1],l[i+1][j])

#import pprint to print the 2D array in a grid format
pprint(l)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194110/int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning `x` and `y` here

```
l=[[0 for x in range(m+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
```

(loop variables escape)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that python variables "leak" outside comprehension scopes, if you do

```
x = "tom"
l = [0 for x in range(10)] 
print x
```

will give you `9` instead of `tom`. Just change the names of variables inside your comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
l=[[0 for x in range(m+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
```

x has been overwritten as an integer. (It's not a string anymore)