# AI Python - TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

In the AI code I am working on, the program has to check if a square on a chessboard is empty. This is represented by a nxn matrix of zeros, and in this part of the code the program checks if the current square (coordinate in the array) is empty:

```
# Check if a square is empty
def square_is_empty(i,j, state):
      if state[i][j] == 0:
         return True
      return False
```

However, I get an output error saying:

```
in square_is_empty
    if state[i][j] == 0:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Despite having read multiple answers about the same issue, I still haven't managed to fix mine!
Thank you

Comment: `state` isn't what you think it is. It's an int, or `state[i]` is an int.

Comment: Can we see how you define `state`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['int' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194110/int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your passed `state` array either is a `int` itself and triggers this error on the access of the `[i]` element or the `state` array has `int`s in it and it triggers this error on the `[j]` element access:

You should probably have a look at how your `state` variable and determine why it might contain `int` instead of list data types. The easiest way to do this would be by just printing it `print state`