# Trying to concatenate a string with values of certain list indecies

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a self project of a 'poker style' game, and I have ran into an error where I am **needing** to display the player's hand to the player, and to do this I have the players stored in a list, as well as their hands, and I am trying to concatenate the two by writing something along the lines of:

```
print ('%s hand is: %s' % str(players[0]), str(hands[0,2]))
                                    ^ # edit: I have realized I was pulling from an incorrect source, modifying threw a new error I will detail below.
# player[] being the list of players
# and hands[] being the list of values pulled to represent cards
```

The error that I am getting when approaching this line is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../poker.py", line 78, in <module>
    poker()
  File "C:/.../poker.py", line 73, in poker
    print ('%s hand is: %s' % str(player[0]), str(hands[0,2]))
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

now even though I can understand the context of what the error is throwing, I haven't even started to look into modules and the `__init__():` style of python, and therefore I can't come close to understanding the issue. If anyone knows what I could do from here I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

**EDIT**

`As requested, I am adding in the contents of the players and hands lists:`

`players begins as an empty set, players = [], and is appended by the values that the user passes as names for input, players 1-x.`

`hands begins as an empty set, hands = [], and is appended by the different 'cards' that are delt. Here are the code for these:`

```
# def number of players first
player_amt = int(raw_input('How many players?: '))
# initialize player number variable
player = 1
# create a list for players to be stored in
players = []
# loop logic: to pull player names and assign a player number
# for as many players as specified above! 
while player <= player_amt:
  # gather player names
  player_name = raw_input('Enter player number %s\'s name: ' % player)
  # adding players to the list
  players.append(player_name)
  # to see the list being appended
  # print players
  # incremental counter
  player += 1

# ---

cards = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
cards_delt = 0
hands = []
while cards_delt < (len(players) * 2):
  card_delt_value = randint(0, len(cards) - 1)
  card_delt = cards[card_delt_value]
  cards_delt += 1
  hands.append(str(card_delt))
```

`After reading through multiple times, I have spotted a bug, coming from the alert from the error that I previously posted, and have notated at to what happened there. I was pulling from an incorrect source, and have fixed this. But, now, upon doing so I am greeted with a new error I will detail it here:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\poker.py", line 78, in <module>
    poker()
  File "C:\...\poker.py", line 73, in poker
    print ('%s hand is: %s' % str(players[0]), str(hands[0,2]))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Lastly, I apologize for the inconsistent nature of this post, If I can do anymore to negate the down votes, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: you need to share with us the content of `player` and `hands` variable, and what value you desire from it. It looks like issue is with `hands[0,2]`, but currently I am not sure what you are trying to achieve there

Comment: Actually, he needs to edit the content of the whole question, he declared player or hands as an integer and the Python interpreter is trying to get an item from an integer instead of a list.

Comment: what does `print(player[0])` and `print(hands[0,2])` print?

Comment: @Nick did you google for the error you are getting "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194110/int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string

I visited this page, reading about arguments it makes sense to me now as to why it was pulling only a single value, the first value passed to it after the modulo, and I then went to fix this, and came across another error, I'm not sure it will let me do something along the lines of: 
`print ('%s' % (example[0,2]))` because it then says something I'm sure equates to list indices must be integers, not tuples.

Comment: You can negate the next few downvotes by opening a new question when you have a new issue. Usually after the first bug of your code has been fixed, there's an answer marked as "The right one", but if you add more bugs to the same question, then that answer is not "The right one" anymore. It makes sense, doesn't it?

Please make a new question with this new bug, next time show us all the `imports` you put in your code along with the definition of the variables that cause this error and I'll be glad to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting says

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

`'__getitem__'` is a method that only collections have, it allows to select one of the items inside of the collection, usually by using an index between two brackets.

That means that you're attempting to apply the index operator [] on an int, not a list. So this means either "hands" or "player" are not a list.

Check that the TypeError is also telling you the type of object you're working with, it's an `'int' object`. Int or integer means this object is an integer number.

Some cool ways to declare a collection in Python are the following:

```
my_list = [item0, item1, item2]
my_tuple = (some_item, other_item, yet_another_item)
my_dictionary = {'apple': 'Manzana', 'good': 'Bueno'}
```

Where `my_dictionary['good']` will return 'Bueno' and `my_list[1]` will return item1.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some errors in your code. This should be able to do what you are trying to, I believe-

```
print ('%s hand is: %s' %(str(player[0]),str(hands[0][2])))
```